# Labeling by using different columns

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule-based

I try to label a layer by using a rule based labeling. What I specifically try to do is to find an expression which says:

"If column 1 shows the attribut x then label layer "Test" by the attribute of column 2"

edit:
I'm using QGis Version 3.10.0-A Coruña.

Comment: what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Sorry and thank you for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is quite easy. First add a new labeling rule, then tell it to filter for all faetures in column 1 which are equal to 'x': `"column 1" LIKE 'x'`

Then tell the rule to label these features with column 2, save the rule and you're done.

[image]